# What redirect URL to use when logging in with GitHUB with OAuth2?

Tags: ios, swift, github, oauth-2.0

I'm new in ios sdk and English. Therefore, sorry for my Eng.
I try to do authentication through github using OAuthSwift.
In the registration of the application (https://github.com/settings/apps), there is need a redirect URL. In the tutorial from raywenderlich.com was an example, they did authorization through Google. They wrote a unique domain in this line that does not work: com.raywenderlich.Incognito. And in Info.plist, we added a Scheme URL with com.raywenderlich.Incognito, so that (as I understood it) when we go to this address after authentication, we’ve got into our application. But if you try to add in the application settings (https://github.com/settings/apps) the Redirect URL: something like com.raywenderlich.Incognito, will generate an error, because github wants the URL to have to be valid. If we put the Valid URL there, then when we will be redirected to this address, we will simply go to it and will not return to the application.

I would be grateful for any help.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Clarity is a bigger problem than English in this question. Try being explicit and direct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect url in OAuth is the url that the authentication provider navigates to when authentication is successful.

- For mobile apps it is the link that launches the app (a sort of deep linking)
- For websites it is the website home screen

Comment: Where can I get this link that will launch the application? 
In the settings of the application, if you specify a non-valid URL, then in the settings of the application in GitHub you will not be able to specify it.
If you specify a valid URL, then it will simply go to this site, and not redirect to the application

Comment: @AuRoom - The redirect_uri is a page on your website that handles the callback with your OAuth token parameters. You need to create this page to process information returned to you from OAuth.